# Django localization: labels don't get updated

Tags: django, localization, po, mo

I'm going crazy guys, my labels are not updated in my views after running "`makemessages`" and "`compilemessages`"!
This is what I tried so far:

1. make sure there is no "`fuzzy`" strings around in PO files
2. delete MO files
3. relaunch `makemessages` and `compilemessages`
4. delete all .`pyc` files in my project
5. delete browser cache
6. change browser
7. drop the local database and launch synchdb
8. shout to the monitor

the commands I launch are the following:

```
python manage.py makemessages --all --no-obsolete --no-location --no-wrap --traceback
python manage.py compilemessages --traceback
```

Is there any sort of Django caching mechanism related to compiled MO files that I have to empty? What can I do? I'm really furious! -_-'

Comment: Have you restarted the django application? Translations are cached in memory. If it does not help, which labels bugs you?

Comment: I stopped and restarted the test server, but without effect... I currently solved restarting the OS! ...such sadness! I'm still trying to figure out the right and effective way to "refresh" my localizations :P

Comment: After you run the `compilemessages`, you should only need to restart the test server for changes to take effect.

Comment: but that did not work for me :P

Comment: still rebooting with every changed label? or found a solution? facing the same problem right now...

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, I thought.
But, I just incorrectly stated [LOCALE_PATHS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths) setting

Comment: Gotcha! I missed the 'locale' from the end of the path string!

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems related to how django finds translation files: [see here (django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations). Normally, LOCALE_PATHS doesn't need to be defined - just make sure your app is in INSTALLED_APPS (which may seem obvious, but isn't always, for example when having sub-apps).